# Port open/listen but no associated process

Tags: linux, networking, process, port

In the output of `nmap -p- localhost` I get an unknown open tcp port, that's different at each reboot. How can I determine which process opened it and listens through it. I tried many of the usual tools (`netstat`, `ss`, `lsof`) but I cannot find the culprit. Eg. `sudo netstat -pan -Ainet | grep <PORT>` gives no PID/Program name:

`tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:<PORT>   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   -`

Maybe I should analyze the startup sequence? But how so?

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could it potentially be that you've got malware, which masks itself with `-` as name ? Consider trying `pgrep "-"`. Also, try  `lsof` https://stackoverflow.com/a/319997/3701431

Comment: No answer solved my problem. And I don't have it anymore since I reinstalled the OS…

Answer (score 4):

As [hinted at](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446751/117549), `ss` can provide the answer as well; the syntax is:

```
sudo ss --tcp --listening --processes 'sport = 1234'
```

Where `1234` is the port-of-the-day from your nmap scan. This limits the output to TCP ports and shows the process name and PID that is listening on that port. `sudo` is only needed if you want the `--process` flag, which provides the process name and PID.

Comment: I din't know the 'sport = <PORT>' trick, I used a `grep` instead. Either way, here is what I get: `LISTEN      0      64                     *:41673                                *:*` No PID nor Program Name :-(

Comment: Did you run it as root, or with sudo?

Comment: I ran your command exactly as you gave it, from a user account, using sudo. Why?

Comment: If you ran it without root privileges, you wouldn't be able to see the process name/pid; that could have explained the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Netstat does exactly what you ask, when run as root and with the correct flags:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1931/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32296/cupsd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1550/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3198/docker-proxy
```

Also, `ss` is the replacement of `netstat` and takes mostly the same flags, but has a differently formatted output

Comment: Did a similar command (`netstat -pan -Ainet`) that gets the same result:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41673           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  ` This does not give any process name nor PID as I get `-` instead.

Comment: Without sudo it is not similar. You can only see the PID of processes started by your user/groups

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `sudo` in my comment but I used it on my computer, as well as when using `ss` and `lsof`.

Answer (score 2):

Some ports opened by the kernel and by some specific services (NFS, OCFS, ssh tunnels) are not visible with netstat nor ss

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. I was having a rough night chasing ghosts like the question shows in netstat output, but realized I was on a server with NFS exports...